# A way to search by partial package definiton in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, search

Having a series of packages like this:

```
Aa.Bb
Aa.Bb.Xx
Aa.Bb.Cc.Dd
Aa.Bb.Cc.Yy
```

So for example I want to search for packages that have "Bb.Cc" in their path retrieving:

```
Aa.Bb.Cc.Dd
Aa.Bb.Cc.Yy
```

How do I do this in Eclipse Luna, bestowing upon the variety of choices of searching that come with it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Java Search* feature for this. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>)

Select "Search for Package" and "Limit to Declarations".
Use wildcards in the search term: `*Bb.Cc*`

[image: java search]